# Iterate over object. Deconstruct its keys and properties and add new ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

My current JSON structure looks like this.

```
[ {A: 84 , B: 17 , C: 11 } ]
```

I need to construct something that will look like this.

```
   [ { name : "A" , value : 84 , color : "black" },
     { name : "B" , value:  17 , color: "blue" } ,
     { name : "C", value:  11 , color: "amber" } ]
```

So I'll need a new structure with added properties ( this case color)  that will depend on initial key values. "A", "B" or "C".

I don't ask for a complete answer (if you wan't to give one feel free to do it) , I'd just like to know which function will I need for this kind of operations.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do a little better? Are you trying to model a structure? Or are you trying to parse JS objects to JSON and automatically get a color depending on the "name" property?

Comment: where do you get the color property from?

Comment: @LoreV I've built a RESTful API. It returns data in format from the first example. I'm using expressjs and handlebars for templating.I need some additional properties in my data so I can add classes/icons to my html. For example if I'm on a object that hase name: "A" ill add class "red" to my template div.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'll need to add color manually depending on current objects key that I'm constructing. ( If Im on object that has name:"A" ill need to add color:"red" property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using `Object.keys`, `Array.map` functions and auxiliary "*color map*" object:

```
var arr = [ {A: 84 , B: 17 , C: 11 }],
    colorMap = {A:"black", B:"blue", C:"amber"}, // can be extended with any other relations
    current = arr[0];

var result = Object.keys(current).map(function(k) {
    return {'name': k, 'value': current[k], 'color': colorMap[k]};
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4));
```

The `console.log` output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "value": 84,
        "color": "black"
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "value": 17,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "value": 11,
        "color": "amber"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use *for..in* to cycle your keys, then map a new object:

```
var current = [ {A: 84 , B: 17 , C: 11 } ];
var result = [];
for(var key in current[0]){
    var name = key;
    var value = current[0][key];
    var color = "";
    switch(key){
        case "A": 
           color = "black";
           break;
        case "B": 
           color =  "blue";
           break;
        case "C": 
           color =  "amber";
           break;
    };
    result.push({name : name, value : value, color: color});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to destruct anything, a simple loop will suffice to create the new structure:

```
var result = [];
for (var prop in input[0])
     result.push({
         name:  prop,
         value: input[0][prop],
         color: colorForName(prop)
     });
```